# Javascript - Favorite button that saves a cookie and remains saved when user refreshes the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a favorite button for my sample site for class. When I click the button it works and takes the user to the detail page as needed but when I go back to the main page it doesn't update/save the image as a favorite. I've tried to figure it out but I'm a bit new to coding so I'm struggling a bit.

I've tried switching around the format and referring to online references. I played around a bit with ajax but still wasn't able to get it to save.

Javascript:

```
function myFunction(elem) {
        var i = document.getElementById(elem.id);

        if(elem.id <= ids.length) {
            i.addEventListener("click", function() {
                var name = getCookie("imgNum");
                setCookie("imgNum", name, 30);
            });
        }

        var a = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        a.innerHTML = "faved";
        i.parentNode.replaceChild(a, i);

    }

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var iUrl = imgUrl[cname];
        return imgUrl;


    }

    function checkCookie() {
        var name = getCookie("imgNum");
        setCookie("imgNum", name, 30);
    }

    function myFunctionTwo(elem) {
        var y = document.getElementById(elem.id);

    }
```

Comment: Firstly, I would recommend using Local Storage instead of cookies. Secondly, I'm not seeing a method here to read the data that is stored, check if there exists a favorited item, and update the page based on the saved data appropriately when the page loads.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: I agree with Tim. But keep in mind that localstorage is limited to browser.

Comment: If you go back by pressing back button in browser a fresh request may not be made b the browser and a cached page will be shown.